# Remove Core Data from iCloud fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, nspersistentstore

I'm trying to remove Core Data from iCloud using `[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:options:error:]`.
But I get strange output:

```
__93+[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:options:error:]_block_invoke(1982):
CoreData: Ubiquity:  Unable to move content directory to new location:
file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/<UBIQUITY_ID>/    
New: file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/OldUbiquitousContent-mobile~C9439AD0-1E87-4977-9C68-0674F5E2E93B
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x181ab790 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/<UBIQUITY_ID>,     
NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/<UBIQUITY_ID>,
NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/OldUbiquitousContent-mobile~C9439AD0-1E87-4977-9C68-0674F5E2E93B,
NSUnderlyingError=0x181aab50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

<strike>What does it mean?</strike>

How to avoid it? I'm working on iCloud disable/enable feature. Details [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422283/magical-record-and-icloud-enabling-disabling)

## UPDATE:

```
  NSDictionary *iCloudOptions =
  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kICloudContentNameKey, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey,
   iCloudURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey, nil];

// self.lastICloudStoreURL stores NSPersistentStore.URL after stack setup
  BOOL result = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:self.lastICloudStoreURL
                                                                                     options:iCloudOptions
                                                                                       error:&error];
```

Comment: Is there any chance that there's a live persistent store coordinator that has a reference to that persistent store?

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Comment: What options do you send as a parameter? Add more info to your question.

Comment: @TomHarrington, not sure how to check it.

Comment: @purrrminator just updated the question

Comment: @orkenstein I meant, do you have any managed objects, managed object contexts, etc, that represent data that would have been loaded from the persistent store that you're trying to remove?

Comment: @orkenstein Try to remove key-value option for `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey`. So that the error about the wrong permissions will disappear and you gain success removing ubiquitous content. But this is not the end. You'll get another error after the coredata-icloud synchronization starts again (something about transaction journal and zero data). I can't explain more details because I'm so tired of this at the moment. Will continue tomorrow and will let you know if I find something

Comment: @TomHarrington no, it all managed by Magical Record. I do not create any additional.

Comment: @purrrminator, yeah, I can understand you. Sometimes I want every iCloud developer burn in hell.

Comment: @orkenstein If you are using MagicalRecord you should call `[MagicalRecord cleanUp];` before `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL`, so that you can be sure that nothig retains the store before removing.

Comment: Using Magical Record actually has nothing at all to do with whether or not you currently have live managed objects or contexts loaded. It's still Core Data, and the same rules still apply.

Comment: @orkenstein does my advice about removing `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey` option fix your problems? whats the issue status atm?

Comment: @purrrminator, sorry, still have no time to test it. I'll report the result ASAP.

Comment: @orkenstein I assume that we should avoid using the option at all. How do you init core data stack? Do you use MR helper `setupCoreDataStackWithiCloudContainer`? If so, MR adds this option to the store under the hood, which is unwanted behaviour. Will check my assumption later...and try to remove the option from everywhere

Comment: @purrrminator I init stack like this
https://gist.github.com/orkenstein/e84f79b5f9438250328b

Answer (score 2):

Normally (before iOS7), you take the ubiquitousContentURL value from `[fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];`
 and pass it as an option called `NSPersistentStore UbiquitousContentURLKey`, and this is how iCloud know where to keep all of your data in the iCloud account.

In iOS 7 and Mac OS X we don't need to pass a value for that at all, and Apple call URLForUbiquitous ContainerIdentifier automatically under the hood for you.

So the solution looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:kICloudContentNameKey, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey, nil];
NSURL *storeURL = [NSPersistentStore MR_urlForStoreName:[MagicalRecord defaultStoreName]];
BOOL result = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:storeURL options:options error:&error];
```

I suggest you to check WWDC 2013 session 207 to get this things clearly.

Answer (score 1):

NSCocoaErrorDomain error 513 is defined in FoundationErrors.h as `NSFileWriteNoPermissionError`. You don't have the required permissions to write to the location.

This can happen if a managed object context is still using objects that are backed by this store. The context is actively using the file that is being moved, which results in a NSFileCoordinator conflict. Two things are trying to access the file with write permission at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But it must be available in that folder.
Or how to gain access?

Comment: @orkenstein I suggest to improve your question, because you definitley want to know how to successfully remove ubiquitous content, not to find the error 513 description?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, as the original question was "what does this mean?".

Comment: Thanks @quellish! I'll write entire flow tomorrow to finally clarify my issue. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @quellish
Pls check the whole source and issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422283/magical-record-and-icloud-enabling-disabling

Answer (score 0):

The `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:options:error:` method deletes all of the user's local and cloud data—this is probably not what you want. Instead, migrate your store to a new location on disk and use the `NSPersistentStoreRemoveUbiquitousMetadataOption` option with the `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:` method.

See *Disabling iCloud Persistence* at [Removing an iCloud-enabled Persistent Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH3-SW33) in the *iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data*.

Comment: What if I really want to wipe all ubiquitous content while beta testing?

Comment: @purrrminator In that case you do want to use the `removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:options:error:` method. See that same documentation link, but look at the "Starting Over" section.

Comment: Ok, migration iCloud -> local works. Local -> iCloud does not. Local data wiped out with iCloud.
Please, check my [SOURCE](https://github.com/orkenstein/HICloudManager)

Comment: @orkenstein You need to create an empty iCloud store, get that store's URL, and migrate the local store on top of it. See the first paragraph of Migrating User Data to iCloud in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/BestPractices/BestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH6-SW3