# NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL method doesn't return any value and blocks the execution thread

Tags: core-data, icloud, core-data-migration, nspersistentstore

Did anybody experience situation when removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:options:error didn't return any value at all? I do. In my case this method just blocks the thread it's executing in. What can be the reason of such an odd behaviour?

Comment: Do you still have any Core Data objects in memory that use this persistent store (anything, `NSManagedObject`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, etc)? And before you say "no", are you sure?

Comment: Yes, before calling this method I release persistent store coordinator that uses the store I'm trying to remove. I agree, theoretically something somewhere may hold a reference to such an object. But doesn't method supposed to return NO value in this case? What a strange API's design.

Comment: "this method is synchronous. Even while performing network operations and possibly taking a significant length of time, this method will not return until it is finished. Second, there should be absolutely no persistent store coordinators active when performing this operation." (http://www.objc.io/issue-10/icloud-core-data.html). I'm trying to use this method to clear ubiquitous content, but it returns NO without any logs.Please let me know if you reach a success with it.

Comment: After I fixed my storeURL, I have new problem which is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895357/remove-core-data-from-icloud-fails . Does anybody know the solution?